# android: OnDraw in a xml layout

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

MainActivity .java
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Window;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(new GView(this);
}
}
```

start.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/screen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="140dp" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

GView.java
    package com.example.nep;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;

public class GView extends View
{
private Bitmap bmp;
Hikari hikari;

public GView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bit);
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 10 , 10, null);
}
}
```

Above is my code and what im trying to do is to remove `setContentView(new GView(this);` and replace it with `setContentView(R.layout.start);` but i want the GView inside of my second layout, this one

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/screen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="140dp" >
```

its ment to be set like a gameboy would, the screen above and the buttons below, how would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you want to use Gview in your xml layout like other views like imageview. You have a field named **custom** in your layout editor in ecllipse. You can drag and drop like any other view. If you want to write the code programmatically then this should work:

```
<com.mypackage.name.GView
android:id="@+id/gview"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >
```

After its setup like this then your question is answered: Simply use :

```
setContentView(R.layout.main)j;//remove new Gview()
```

Comment: i did as you said but i get a error: Custom view GView is not using the 2- or 3-argument View constructors; XML attributes will not work